# PHP dropdown default value

Tags: php

I have this code,How would you set a default selection in this dropdown menu.

```
<tr><td class="tdt">

<?php te('Hypervisor');?>:</td> <td title='Add more from Hypervisor menu'>
<select validate='required:true' class='mandatory' name='hyp'>
   <option value=''>Select</option>
  <?php 
    foreach ($hyper as $a) {
      $dbid=$a['id'];
      $atype=$a['typedesc']; $s="";
      if (isset($hyp) && $hyp==$a['id']) $s=" SELECTED ";
      echo "<option $s value='$dbid' title='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
  ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

I have a table connected to this code called hypervisors.in that table theres id field and typedesc field.I'd like to set "ESXi" as the default value which is represented by an ID num 1.

Update 2:

```
$sql="SELECT id,typedesc FROM hypervisors";
$sth=db_execute($dbh,$sql);
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    $hyper[$r['id']]=$r;
```

that is SQL query

Comment: This exact way. Side note: when you are generating HTML, **always** `htmlspecialchars` any dynamic content.

Comment: We use `selected="selected"` http://jsfiddle.net/wFmBE/

Comment: @Mr.Alien: [Not necessary](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute).

Comment: title attribute is unnecessary

Comment: @Adam may I guess I got this thing wrong...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon. I have a table connected to this code called hypervisors.in that table theres id field and typedesc field.I'd like to set "ESXi" as the default value which is represented by an ID num 1.

Comment: @Mr.Alien in: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp there are no title attribute.

Comment: @Adam I have no clue what are you saying

Comment: @Mr.Alien there are title attribute in OPTION which is unnecessary. Should be removed.

Comment: @Adam oh, I don't care about that, I just provided a solution to him which he was looking for :)

Comment: Anybody else who can shed some light on this situation ??

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
  foreach ($hyper as $a) {
      $dbid=$a['id'];
      $atype=$a['typedesc'];
      if (isset($hyp) && $hyp==$dbid) {
         echo "<option selected='selected' value='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";
      } else {
         echo "<option value='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";
      }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .Your code did work but it won't select anything as default or do i have to set the default value myself.thanks

Comment: @Carter this is because of your condition `$hyp==$dbid` is not working. check that `$hyp` has some value or not.

Comment: Thanks  Broken Heart ღ.My code work perfectly without the default value.Its just it'd be convenient to set default so the user can easily navigate the form without making a whole lot of selections

Comment: @Carter ohk, my pleasure to help you. in future you can ask for other problems solution.

Comment: Also, adding this logic with the ternary operators lessens the code within one line. :)

Answer (score 1):

With selected within the option tag, you set the selected default value of your dropdown
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
if (isset($hyp) && $hyp==$a['id']){
      $s=" SELECTED ";
      echo "<option $s value='$dbid' selected>$atype</option>\n";
}
else {
     echo "<option value='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but the code didn't work i'm getting a syntax error. appreciate your help

Comment: Did you replace your    if (isset($hyp) && $hyp==$a['id']) $s=" SELECTED ";
      echo "<option $s value='$dbid' title='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";    with mine?